# How to snap edge to axis/grid?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I want to move the whole object up by snapping the edge (highlighted in white/orange) to the X axis (red axis). What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to:

- In *Edit* mode, put the 3D cursor on the surface you want to snap.
- Come back to *Object* mode and put the origin of the object to the 3D cursor.
- Choose the *Type of Element to Snap* to *Increment* and enable the *Absolute Grid Alignment* option.
- Now either enable the *Snap* option or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> as a shortcut to enable it momentarily.

[image]